# Is it possible to show labels for all lines?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Basically I have chartJS based line chart, with two lines. X axis has dates, and Y axes has price.

There is two lines (one for average price and one for minimum price).

So I was wondering, if it is at all possible to so that lets say I hover over a point for minimum price, the average price point's label pops up as well, and vice versa.

Or if that is not possible, maybe it is possible to make it so each label contains both values (the min and average price for that particular day).

Here is the code, I have so far:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('price-history').getContext('2d');
    ctx.height = 150;
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: <?= json_encode($priceChangeData['labels']); ?>,
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'Minimali kaina',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgb(64, 127, 178)',
                    borderColor: 'rgb(64, 127, 178)',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    data: <?= json_encode($priceChangeData['line']['price_min']); ?>,
                    fill: false
                },
                {
                    label: 'Vidutinė kaina',
                    backgroundColor: '#686868',
                    borderColor: '#686868',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    data: <?= json_encode($priceChangeData['line']['price_avg']); ?>,
                    fill: false
                }
            ],
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            layout: {
                padding: {
                    left: 20,
                    right: 15
                }
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: false,
                        labelString: 'Data'
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    stacked: false,
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: false,
                        labelString: 'Kaina'
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are talking about the tooltip­*'s* label. In that case, you can set tooltips mode to [**`index`**](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/modes.html#index) in your chart­*'s* options config, like so :

```
options: {
      tooltips: {
         mode: 'index'
      },
      ...
```

**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ ⧩**

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('price-history').getContext('2d');
ctx.height = 150;
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
      labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'], //<?= json_encode($priceChangeData['labels']); ?>,
      datasets: [{
         label: 'Minimali kaina',
         backgroundColor: 'rgb(64, 127, 178)',
         borderColor: 'rgb(64, 127, 178)',
         borderWidth: 1,
         data: [3, 1, 4, 2, 5], //<?= json_encode($priceChangeData['line']['price_min']); ?>,
         fill: false
      }, {
         label: 'Vidutinė kaina',
         backgroundColor: '#686868',
         borderColor: '#686868',
         borderWidth: 1,
         data: [2, 4, 1, 5, 3], //<?= json_encode($priceChangeData['line']['price_avg']); ?>,
         fill: false
      }],
   },
   options: {
      responsive: true,
      tooltips: {
         mode: 'index'
      },
      layout: {
         padding: {
            left: 20,
            right: 15
         }
      },
      scales: {
         xAxes: [{
            display: true,
            scaleLabel: {
               display: false,
               labelString: 'Data'
            }
         }],
         yAxes: [{
            display: true,
            stacked: false,
            scaleLabel: {
               display: false,
               labelString: 'Kaina'
            }
         }]
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="price-history"></canvas>
```

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for! Than you so much!